# How do i turn my factors into a number in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset (called nordland) that has two columns; Firm name and date.
I want to plot this into ggplot so that it shows how many firms are in a given date. How do i do this?

When i run this:

```
plot <- ggplot(nordland, aes(x = nordland$Date, y = nordland$`Firm name`)) +
geom_col() +
labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of firms", Title = "Number of new firms per month")
```

i get ALL the names of the firms on the Y-axis instead of number of firms.

Here is the minimum code that is relevant:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

url <- "https://w2.brreg.no/kunngjoring/kombisok.jsp?datoFra=01.01.2019&datoTil=25.09.2019&id_region=100&id_fylke=-+-+-&id_niva1=2&id_bransje1=0"

webpage <- read_html(url)

newfirmdata <- html_nodes(webpage, "td td:nth-child(2) p")
newfirmtext <- html_text(newfirmdata)
newfirmtext <- gsub("\n", "", newfirmtext)
newfirmtext <- gsub(" ","", newfirmtext)
Firmname <- data.frame(newfirmtext)
Firmname <- rename(Firmname, "Firm name" = "newfirmtext")
Firmname <- Firmname [-1, ]
Firmname <- as.factor(Firmname)
Firmname <- unique(Firmname)

datedata <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(6) p")
datetext <- html_text(datedata)
datetext <- as.Date(datetext, "%d.%m.%Y")
Datename <- data.frame(datetext)
Datename <- Datename [-1, ]

totaldata <- data.frame(Firmname, Datename)
totaldata <- rename(totaldata, "Firm Name" = "Firmname", "Date" = "Datename")

nordland <- data.frame(totaldata$`Firm Name`[1:1052], totaldata$Date[1:1052])
nordland <- rename(nordland, "Firm name" = "totaldata..Firm.Name..1.1052.", "Date" = "totaldata.Date.1.1052.")
```

I excpected that the plot would show the number of firms in a given date, and instead it shows the names of the firms. This creates a convoluted graph that is unreadable.

Comment: Where is `totaldata` coming from? It might help if you are able to share this in your question, such as `dput(head(totaldata))`

Comment: I forgot to add it back in, Sorry! It should be visible now.

Comment: Of course, it is added now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `geom_bar` (where `geom_col` is its wrapper with `stat="identity"` requiring y and x mapped from data set). However, you only need x with a count and `?geom_bar` defaults with `stat = "count"`.

Also, never use `$` referencing inside `aes()` but unquoted data frame column names and avoid naming objects as built-in functions like base R's `plot()` that can cause naming collisions. Finally, the argument *title* should be lower case and R is case sensitive.

```
myplot <- ggplot(nordland, aes(x = Date)) +
           geom_bar() +
           labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of firms", 
                title = "Number of new firms per month") +
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

If you really intend to use `geom_col`, add a new column of all 1's, so `geom_col` sums for graphing:

```
nordland$N <- 1
myplot <- ggplot(nordland, aes(x = Date, y = N)) +
          geom_col() +
          labs(x = "Date", y = "Number of firms",
               title = "Number of new firms per month")
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: Plot with Title]

Comment: Ah, so it was that easy! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. See edit regarding *title* which should be lower case to render on graph.